# simulate key in games

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I have a problem. I made some program with c# to help me in games. The logic is very simple. I used SendKey() method and low-level procs and they works correclly in software but doesn't work in games. any body has some idea?
Thank you all.

Comment: I want use a program to do an action priodly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding Send keys is a pretty basic anti-cheat measure. And you did just explain why :D

Send Key only works if the other side is reacting to what the Windowing System is telling it. Games often use raw input, to have better reactiontimes and avoid everything Windows might do to the input. And this rather simply cheat/bot approach too.